# Digital Ocean server allowing access to only the first view in laravel application

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel-4, digital-ocean

I have a laravel application that I am trying to delpoy into a digital ocean server. I have chmod the public directory to 777 inside `var/www/myapp/` and have set the root directory as

/var/www/myapp/public/ in the sites-enabled configuration file.

But  I am able access only the default `/` route in the application.

This is how the conf file looks like now

```
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/schoolcms/public/

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        <Directory /var/www/schoolcms/public/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Would be great if someone show me how to fix this. BTW I am on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Have you chmoded recursively to sub-directories as well or only the root directory? Btw check error logs if they turn anything.

Comment: yeah - did it recursively

Comment: How you turned mod_rewrite on?

Comment: That turned out to be the problem, thanks